# Does CSS class order have any impact on performance?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, selector

Lets say we have elements like:

```
<div class="a">
   <div class="b">something</div>
   <div class="b">something</div>
   <div class="b">something</div>
   <div class="b c">something</div>
   <div class="b">something</div>
   ... 1500 more
</div>
```

Is there any performance difference if we use:

**document.querySelector(".a .b.c");**

or

**document.querySelector(".a .c.b");**

I am asking this because browser reads selector from right to left, so this means that performance should be impacted.

Comment: I believe `a c.b` is faster, because it finds all the classes with a, then all the classes with c, which there is only one of.

Comment: **Premature Optimization Is the Root of All Evil!** Do you have a performance problem? Does your profiler show that a lot of time is being spent running `document.querySelector`? If so, worry about it then … and test on your real world situation rather than a hypothetical. Don't waste time optimising something that doesn't matter.

Comment: I would also say if you have 1500 lines of code like that perhaps you want to optimise that with some pagination rather than your selector

Comment: @symlink don't js selector engines read selectors from right to left?

Comment: I edited answer and added dots for classes.

Comment: You could create your own performance test for it: https://jsperf.com/ but if you are that bothered about performance, you should probably be chaining `getElementsByClassname` rather than using `querySelector`